# AVPlayerViewController back to fullscreen mode from picture in picture application crash

Tags: swift, avplayerviewcontroller

When we go back to fullscreen mode from PIP mode, Video continue to play in fullscreen but when I tapped on Pause button application crashed. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
func playerViewControllerDidStopPictureInPicture(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController) {
        guard let player = self.moviePlayer?.player else {
            return
        }
    }


func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, restoreUserInterfaceForPictureInPictureStopWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let currentviewController = navigationController?.visibleViewController
        if currentviewController != playerViewController{
            currentviewController?.present(playerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else {
            present(playerViewController, animated: false)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the full code for PauseButton Action?

Comment: @GhulamMustafa I am using native player so Play/Pause is handle by player itself.

Comment: Can you share the error message?